# Value ! is not a member of Actor

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I've got an Actor class that manages a list of Actors. When it receives a message of a certain type, it passes it off to each of the Actors it knows about.

```
 var loggers : List[Logger]    

def receive = {
  ...
  // log request
  case logmessage : LogMessage => {
      // send message to each logger (if none, nothing happens)
      for (logger <- loggers)
        logger ! logmessage
  }
  ...     
}
```

I'm getting a compile error on `logger ! logmessage` : "value ! is not a member of (package).Logger". The ! makes this very difficult to google. The Logger class compiles, having its own receive method, one line including `self ! PoisonPill`, meaning the ! operator works there. They're in the same package.

Comment: please show the code for your Logger class.

Comment: It extends Actor and implements receive. I was going to edit it in and remove the body but that's literally all it is right now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming `Logger extends Actor`

In Akka, message sending is done between `ActorRef`s, not `Actor`s. Every actor's `self` is an `ActorRef` instance. So you would want to change your loggers var to be `var loggers: List[ActorRef]`.

Better yet, you could use an [`ActorSelection`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/#akka.actor.ActorSelection), which has a `!` method that sends the message to all actor refs in the selection. You can find methods for creating an `ActorSelection` in the Actor's [`context`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/#akka.actor.ActorContext).

P.S. You can use the ["#" page](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/#index.index-_) on the Akka Scaladocs to find methods that start with symbols. On that page you can see that there is a `!` defined on `ScalaActorRef` and `ScalaActorSelection`, both of which are implicit upgrades from `ActorRef` and `ActorSelection`.

Comment: Given an Actor object, is it possible to get an ActorRef?

Comment: Every Actor has an `implicit final val self: ActorRef` ([see the docs](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/#akka.actor.Actor))

Comment: As Dylan shows, you should *never* directly access an Actor object (except tests).  If you do, you've violated one of Akka's most basic principles. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/general/addressing.html#addressing.